# How to install fonts?

Tags: pi-3, linux

I very much like Adobe's Utopia fonts and already installed it in other Linux distris, but with Raspbian it doesn't work.

I copied them first to `/home/pi/.fonts` and then also to `/usr/local/share/fonts`. Neither of these works.

The font files have the extensions `.afm`, `.bdf`, .`pfb`. I also converted this last one to `.pfa`.

Answer (score 1):

As much I know, it mainly supports TrueType Fonts (ie. .ttf format). Try converting your fonts to ttf first. From [this link](https://onlinefontconverter.com/).

Comment: Thanks a lot Sharma! .ttf was the answer. The site you made the link to didn't really work, but I found another site that did the job.

Comment: @Antonio lease provide the link so the answer can be improved and marked as a answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The site is http://www.fontconverter.org/